# Constructing a group from any set of groups

Tags: group-theory

How can we construct a group from any non-empty set of groups that is not in the original set (i.e. not isomorphic to any of its elements)?

Comment: Interestingly enough, [essentially the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045671/for-any-set-q-of-groups-why-does-there-exist-a-group-g-that-is-not-isomorphic-t) was asked almost simultaneously with yours. Perhaps someone is having a final?

Comment: wow... wish I waited before asking haha. finals? how i miss those days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a a set $X$ of groups take a group $G$ s.t. $|G|>|x|$ for all $x\in X$. Then 
$G\not\cong x $ for $x\in X$, because there cannot be any bijection $G\to x$, and an isomorphism of groups must always be a bijection.

Only relevant to the previous versions of your question:

Your question needs clarification (without requiring any relation of the group to be constructed with the groups that are given your question is trivially answered). As it is stated now, I can say the following:

A group structure can be defined on any nonempty set. So given any set (whether the elements are groups or not), you can find a group structure on it: If it is finite, use the structure of $\mathbb Z_n$, if countably infinite, the structure of $\mathbb Z$ will do, and for all other cardinalities an application of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem will give you the existence of the group structure.

(This was an answer pertaining to a part of the original question that was edited out:) Since you might have a finite set of infinite groups you cannot guarantee that the group you construct is isomorphic to one of the elements of your given set.

Comment: My bad ... edited!

Comment: well I don't want any group, I want a group guaranteed to NOT be isomorphic to any of the groups in the set. So I can't use a fixed group as an answer like Z or Zn

Comment: why is it that G is not isomorphic to any element in X?

Comment: so if you have a set X of cardinality c, and you construct a group of cardinality d>c, then you're implying none of the elements in X has cardinality d. how is this true?

Comment: My bad, this was obviously wrong. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If the given set of groups is the empty set, it is impossible to find a Group that is (isomorphic to) an element of this set.

With the problematic case of the empty et of Groups excluded, the Axiom of Choice allows us to pick an element of any (non-empty) set of groups.

Comment: My bad ... edited!

Comment: A group can't be empty because it must contain an identity element.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a set of groups and suppose that it is denumerable with $\mathbb{Z}\in G$. So, we can suppose that $G=\{G_n:n\in\omega\}$. Define $+:G\times G\rightarrow G$ such that $+(G_n,G_m)=G_{n+m}$. It's clear that $\langle G,+\rangle$ is a group and $G\simeq\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: My bad ... edited!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a set of groups, the set of their cardinalities is bounded above. Choose a cardinal that is strictly larger than that bound. Now construct a group $G$ whose underlying set has cardinality at least as large as that chosen cardinal (for example the group of permutations of that cardinal). It follows that $G$ is not isomorphic to any of your original groups.

Comment: why is the new group not isomorphic to any of the original's elements?

Comment: are you saying i should pick a cardinal greater than the cardinality of the set itself or greater than the max order of a group in it?

Comment: I rewrote that sentence to clarify.